# Error when using Snakemake variable in R script

Tags: python, r, snakemake

I have got the following `Snakemake` rule:

```
rule deseq2:
    input:
        salmon=expand("salmon/{sample}/quant.sf", sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        xlsx="deseq2/deseq2_diff_trx.xlsx",
        rdata="deseq2/dds.Rdata",
    params:
        map_with,
        genome,
        gtf,
    log:
        "logs/deseq2/deseq2.log"
    conda:
        "envs/deseq2.yml"
    threads: config["resources"]["deseq2"]["cpu"]
    resources: 
        runtime=config["resources"]["deseq2"]["time"]
    script:
        "scripts/deseq2.R"
```

The part of that R script that the rule runs that gives an error is when I save a variable to a file name in the output section of the `snakemake` variable:

```
save(dds, snakemake@output[[2]])
```

```
Error in save(dds, snakemake@output[[2]]) : 
  object ‘snakemake@output[[2]]’ not found
```

Earlier in the script I access the params part of the `snakemake` variable in a similar way, but without any errors:

```
map.with <- snakemake@params[[1]]
genome <- snakemake@params[[2]]
gtf <- snakemake@params[[3]]
```

When I print the `snakemake` variable I get this (only partial,relevant output):

```
An object of class "Snakemake"
Slot "input":
[[1]]
[1] "salmon/Control-1/quant.sf"

[[2]]
[1] "salmon/Control-2/quant.sf"

[[3]]
[1] "salmon/Control-Hypoxia-1/quant.sf"

[[4]]
[1] "salmon/Control-Hypoxia-2/quant.sf"

$salmon
[1] "salmon/Control-1/quant.sf"         "salmon/Control-2/quant.sf"        
[3] "salmon/Control-Hypoxia-1/quant.sf" "salmon/Control-Hypoxia-2/quant.sf"


Slot "output":
[[1]]
[1] "deseq2/deseq2_diff_trx.xlsx"

[[2]]
[1] "deseq2/dds.Rdata"

$xlsx
[1] "deseq2/deseq2_diff_trx.xlsx"

$rdata
[1] "deseq2/dds.Rdata"


Slot "params":
[[1]]
[1] "salmon"

[[2]]
[1] "hg38"

[[3]]
[1] "/home/user/Documents/references/gtf/hg38/gencode.v43.annotation.gtf"
```

I have also saved the work space to a file for debugging as suggest by the `snakemake` web site. When I load this into R I can do the following things:

```
> snakemake@output[["rdata"]]
[1] "deseq2/dds.Rdata"

> snakemake@output[[2]]
[1] "deseq2/dds.Rdata"
```

But when the above code is include in the proper script I get the object not found (see above) error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but I think you want:

```
save(dds, file = snakemake@output[[2]])
```

In your code, `snakemake@output[[2]]` appears as an object to be saved, not as the file to save to. The relevant bit from `?save` should be:

```
Usage:

     save(..., list = character(),
          file = stop("'file' must be specified"),
          ascii = FALSE, version = NULL, envir = parent.frame(),
          compress = isTRUE(!ascii), compression_level,
          eval.promises = TRUE, precheck = TRUE)
     
     save.image(file = ".RData", version = NULL, ascii = FALSE,
                compress = !ascii, safe = TRUE)
     
Arguments:

     ...: the names of the objects to be saved (as symbols or character
          strings).

    list: A character vector containing the names of objects to be
          saved.

    file: a (writable binary-mode) connection or the name of the file
          where the data will be saved (when tilde expansion is done).
          Must be a file name for ‘save.image’ or ‘version = 1’.
```